# update deduction to sql vb doesnt work

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I wanted to update deduction of stock to sql through vb, it doesn't show error but it wont update.
i wish the music_copies in sql got updated with the new result of txtstock.text - txtquan.txt however it show successfully purchase but when i refresh the data, it shows the same as previous

```
  Private Sub btnwalkinadd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnwalkinadd.Click
     Dim con As New SqlConnection
     Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
     Dim rd As SqlDataReader 

    txtcal.Text = txtstock.Text - txtquan.Text 'This only for my reference
    Try

        If txtcal.Text >= 0 Then
           con.ConnectionString = "Server=KAVIER;Database=vb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
            con.Open()
            cmd.Connection = con

            Dim updatecmd As String = "UPDATE music SET music_copies = ' " & txtstock.Text - txtquan.Text & "' WHERE mus_id = '" & txtid.Text & "'"

            updatecmd = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 'execute the command

            MsgBox("Successfully Purchased")
            con.Close()
            Else
                MsgBox("Insufficient Stock")
            End If

            txttotal.Clear()
            txtartist.Clear()
            txtprice.Clear()
            txtid.Clear()
            txtgenre.Clear()
            txtalbum.Clear()
            txtcal.Clear()
            txtstock.Clear()


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but your code is **packed** with flaws. The connection needs a connection string. The command needs a connection and a command text. The connection, command and reader needs to be disposed at the end. You never use the reader. Your query is open for SQL-injection. You need to turn option strict on.

Comment: ok... i manage to added in what u mentioned and finally it works =) thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code.

```
Private Sub btnwalkinadd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnwalkinadd.Click
     Dim con As New SqlConnection
     Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
     Dim rd As SqlDataReader 

    txtcal.Text = txtstock.Text - txtquan.Text 'This only for my reference
    Try

        If txtcal.Text >= 0 Then
           con.ConnectionString = "Server=KAVIER;Database=vb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
            con.Open()
            cmd.Connection = con

            cmd.commandtext = "UPDATE music SET music_copies = ' " & txtstock.Text - txtquan.Text & "' WHERE mus_id = '" & txtid.Text & "'"

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 'execute the command

            MsgBox("Successfully Purchased")
            con.Close()
            Else
                MsgBox("Insufficient Stock")
            End If

            txttotal.Clear()
            txtartist.Clear()
            txtprice.Clear()
            txtid.Clear()
            txtgenre.Clear()
            txtalbum.Clear()
            txtcal.Clear()
            txtstock.Clear()


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

it was the problem with your command text.you have given command text as updatecmd  and defined it as string but executed sql commadn cmd which has no command text to be executed.you should initialize the commmand to be executed as command text.

Comment: thanks =))) i manage to fix it with comment above